# How does Haskell convert integer literals to different types?

Tags: haskell

I have following anonymous function:

```
*Exercises> g = \(Sum n) -> Sum (n - 1)
```

I use it like:

```
*Exercises> g (Sum 56)
Sum {getSum = 55}
*Exercises> g 56
Sum {getSum = 55}
```

The second example, how does the compiler convert `56` to `Sum 56`?

In the prelude, I saw that `Sum` is an instance of `Num`, but it not clear about the conversion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Haskell sees an integer literal such as `56`, it interprets it as `fromInteger 56`. The type of `fromInteger` is `Num a => Integer -> a`, so the type of this code is `Num a => a`. (Any type, here called `a`, which is a member of the `Num` class.)

This means that when you use it in a context where a member of `Num` is expected (`Sum` in your case), it will "set" `a` to `Sum`, and pick the version of `fromInteger` of type `Integer -> Sum`. Thus `fromInteger 56 :: Sum`.