# How it becomes to concrete type?

Tags: haskell

I have following value:

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> [1,2,3,4,5 :: Sum Integer]
[Sum {getSum = 1},Sum {getSum = 2},Sum {getSum = 3},Sum {getSum = 4},Sum {getSum = 5}]
```

As you can see, `1..4` are Integers and `5` is a type of `Sum Integer`.
How the contents of the list become to the type `Sum Integer`? There are more `Integers` inside, why does not it become to `Integer`?

Comment: The answer [to this other question you asked a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802606/how-does-haskell-convert-integer-literals-to-different-types) should cover this too I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1..4 are Integers and 5 is a type of Sum Integer

Not exactly. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` is of type `Num t => [t]`, where the type `t` is an instance of `Num` waiting to be inferred to a rigid type.

When you point that one of the elements is `Sum Integer`, the compiler infers all the other elements of the list to the same type.

So, the list becomes of type `[1,2,3,4,5 :: Sum Integer] :: [Sum Integer]`, just what you see in the output.